# What nullable type to use for varbinary column in F# EFCore?

Tags: f#, ef-core-2.1

I have an MSSQL database column that is a nullable varbinary(8). When I try to make the field nullable in my F# record, i get the following error:

> "A generic construct requires that the type 'byte[]' have a public default constructor"

Neither `Nullable<byte[]>`, `Nullable<Byte[]>`, `Nullable<Byte list>` or `Nullable<seq<byte>>` get beyond this error.

I have omitted other fields for brevity.

```ml
[<Table("SurveyResponse"); CLIMutable>]
type SurveyResponse = {
    mutable ContactId: Nullable<byte[]>
}
```

Is there a nullable F# type I can use that EF Core will properly translate to a varbinary(8)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have much experience with EF and don't have all the setup to try this, but the error message you are getting is coming from the F# type checker and not from EF.

The problem is that `Nullable<'T>` requires that the type `'T` is a value type - the purpose of `Nullable` is to add `null` to other types that do not have `null` as value such as `int` or `float`. However, an array can be `null` on its own and it should not need`Nullable` for this.

So, assuming EF does not do anything special here, I think the following should do the trick:

```
[<Table("SurveyResponse"); CLIMutable>]
type SurveyResponse = {
    mutable ContactId: byte[]
}
```

Given a `SurveyResponse` value `sr`, you can check `sr.ContactId <> null` to handle `null` values.

Comment: This does indeed work, I made the assumption that you could not assign null to an array when creating the record.

`{ ContactId = null }` Thank you!